# Generate numbers and write them to the clipboard

Tags: javascript

I want to let the user input a min and a max value, then i try to generate the numbers from min to max and save the result into the clipboard.

However, i always get `Uncaught ReferenceError: generateNumbers is not defined` and can't explain why.

```js
window.onLoad = function()
{
  function generateNumbers()
  {
    var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
    var result = "";

    for(var i=min; i < max; i++ )
    {
      result = result + i + ";";
    }
    copyToClipboard(result);
    console.log(result);
  }

  function copyToClipboard(text)
  {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
  }
}
```

```html
<label>MIN: </label><input type="text" id="min"/><br>
<label>MAX: </label><input type="text" id="max"/><br>
<button onclick="generateNumbers">send</button>
```

**JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/n303o8tz/1/

**SOLVED JSFIDDLE:** https://jsfiddle.net/n303o8tz/4/

Comment: Just use `addEventListener` in JavaScript, it's easier than fiddling around with attributes and scope.

Comment: There's no point in defining the functions inside a window.onload event, and it's  causing the problem you're having.

Comment: @ManoDestra `generateNumbers` isn't in global scope.

Comment: Yeah, he needs to remove that from there, of course. That indeed makes no sense. The window.onload handler is entirely redundant and unnecessary. Removed my previous comment as it makes no sense now that the question has been edited.

Comment: Thank you guys, i was able to solve it by adding an Event Listener! :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You need to remove that window.onload part and simply call the function in your button's onclick handler.

Here's one way of doing it:

```
<meta charset="UTF-8">
<script>
function generateNumbers() {
    var min = parseInt(document.getElementById("min").value);
    var max = parseInt(document.getElementById("max").value);
    var result = "";
    for (var i = min; i <= max; i++) {
        result += i;
        if (i < max) {
            result += ";";
        }
    }

    console.log(result);
    copyToClipboard(result);
}

function copyToClipboard(text) {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
}
</script>
<input id="min" type="text" value="1">
<input id="max" type="text" value="10">
<button onclick="generateNumbers()">Test</button>
```

Answer (score 1):

The problem is, that the function `generateNumbers` is not in a global scope. It is possible to solve this problem by adding an Event Listener to the button instead of using the onClick attribute:

```js
  document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click",generateNumbers);
  
  function generateNumbers()
  {
    var min = document.getElementById("min").value;
    var max = document.getElementById("max").value;
    var result = "";

    for(var i=min; i <= max; i++ )
    {
      result = result + i + ";";
    }
    copyToClipboard(result);
  }

  function copyToClipboard(text)
  {
    window.prompt("Copy to clipboard: Ctrl+C, Enter", text);
  }
```

```html
<label>MIN: </label><input type="text" id="min"/><br>
<label>MAX: </label><input type="text" id="max"/><br>
<button id="mybutton">send</button>
```

Comment: Simplify to `document.getElementById("mybutton").addEventListener("click", generateNumbers);`